# Вложенные запросы

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql

Дело в чем. Попросили меня сделать выборку из 3 таблиц:

```
Student(Table)
ID | FIO | Adress | Group

Link(Table)
IDT | Group | Subject

Teacher(Table)
ID | FIO | Adress
```

В результате выборки мы должны видеть такие поля:

```
Student.FIO | Link.Subject | Teacher.FIO
```

Ну я как бы написал запрос:

```
SELECT Student.FIO, link.Subject, Teacher.FIO
FROM (Student INNER JOIN link ON student.Group = link.Group) INNER JOIN Teacher ON link.IDT = Teacher.ID
WHERE (`Student`.`FIO` LIKE '%Pupkin%');
```

Все делает отлично, тут мне сказали, якобы он не вложенный, сделай вложенным. Что и как ума не приложу. Скоро сломаю `phpmyadmin`. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну в данном случае задачу вы решили правильно...<br>
Но знать о вложеных запросах надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А для чего тут нужен вложенный? чтобы помедленнее работал что ли?
Вложенность можно в разных фразах применять. Например в списке выбираемых полей

```
SELECT Student.FIO, link.Subject, 
 (SELECT Teacher.FIO FROM Teacher WHERE Teacher.ID = link.IDT) AS TFIO 
FROM Student 
     JOIN link ON student.Group = link.Group
WHERE Student.FIO LIKE '%Pupkin%'
```

Comment: Я вот начитался тут про вложенность и действительно написано что замедляет производительность. Спасибо добрый человек за помощь.

Comment: дыкх - вложенность даже не эксперту должна показаться непроизводительной :)

Answer (score 2):

Чето замудрено все, так не пойдет?

```
SELECT st.FIO, ln.subject, tch.fio 
FROM Student st
LEFT JOIN Link ln ON st.group=ln.group
LEFT JOIN Teacher tch ON ln.IDT=tch.ID
WHERE St.FIO LIKE '%Pupkin%'
```

Comment: это ведь не вложенность, или нет? просто перефразировал SELECT

Comment: А зачем вложенность, полностью согласен с @renegator, запросы с вложенными подзапросами на порядок медленнее выполняются.